# ActiveRecord has_and_belongs_to_many: find models with all given elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm implementing a search system that uses name, tags, and location. There is a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `Server` and `Tag`. Here's what my search method currently looks like:

```
def self.search(params)
  @servers = Server.all

  if params[:name]
    @servers = @servers.where "name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:name]}%"
  end

  if params[:tags]
    @tags = Tag.find params[:tags].split(",")
    # How do I eliminate servers that do not have these tags?
  end

  # TODO: Eliminate those that do not have the location specified in params.
end
```

The tags parameter is just a comma-separated list of IDs. My question is stated in a comment in the `if params[:tags]` conditional block. How can I eliminate servers that do not have the tags specified?

Bonus question: any way to speed this up? All fields are optional, and I am using Postgres exclusively.

**EDIT**

I found a way to do this, but I have reason to believe it will be extremely slow to run. Is there any way that's faster than what I've done? Perhaps a way to make the database do the work?

```
tags = Tag.find tokens
servers = servers.reject do |server|
    missing_a_tag = false

    tags.each do |tag|
        if server.tags.find_by_id(tag.id).nil?
            missing_a_tag = true
        end
    end

    missing_a_tag
end
```

Comment: How tags are related to servers, I mean the association?

Comment: Both have has_and_belongs_to_many, and use a join table called servers_tags.

Comment: By "eliminate" do you mean destroy (i.e. remove from the database)?

Comment: No, just eliminate from the local @tags collection. This is a search function and I only want to return servers that match the search parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Retrieve the servers with all the given tags with

```
if params[:tags]
  tags_ids = params[:tags].split(',')
  @tags = Tag.find(tags_ids) 
  @servers = @servers.joins(:tags).where(tags: {id: tags_ids}).group('servers.id').having("count(*) = #{tags_ids.count}")
end
```

The `group(...).having(...)` part selects the servers with **all** requested tags. If you're looking for servers which have **at least** one of the tags, remove it.

With this solution, the search is done in a single SQL request, so it will be better than your solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work properly. It returns no servers even though there are servers with the tag.